# DidSelectRowForIndexPath not called after calling select row programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to select row programmatically and so the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will trigger

what I have tried is :

```
   int index = (int)[[[notification userInfo]objectForKey:@"index"]integerValue];

   [_tagstableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]   animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

the cell does selecting it self , but the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` doesn't trigger 
however it does trigger when I using manual Tap on 1 of my cells :/

how can I convince the `didSelectRowAtindexPath` to get triggered after a programmatically selection ?

Comment: please comment the downvote ,so i can improve the question :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are explicitly selecting the row, you need to explicitly call the delegate method if that is your desire.

Simply add:

```
[self tableView:_tagstableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];
```

after the call to `selectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I have tried it :( but it says no visible interface declares the selector `didSelectRow ...` :(

Comment: Are you calling this from within the view controller that implements the table view's delegate?

Comment: yes ! i call it from 'UIViewController' that has '<UITableViewDelegate ,UITableViewDatasource>'

Comment: sorry for the late reply it wad 5 am ... I fall asleep

Comment: I didnt copy paste it as is :-) it really doesnt see the method :-(

Comment: i used this 1 '[_tagstableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0]];'

Comment: As I show in my answer, you need to call this on `self` (the view controller), not the table view.

Comment: Imo Apple should call the didselect... by their self :-///

Comment: No, they shouldn't. The delegate is called to let you know that the user did something. When you explicitly perform the action (such as selecting the row), you already know it has been selected.